# 1-dimensional random walk with stops: prove it converges almost surely

Tags: probability, random-walk

> Let $p\in (0,1)$ be fixed, and let $q=1-p$. A frog performs a (discrete time) random walk on the 1-dimensional lattice $\mathbb{Z}$ the following way:
>
> The initial position is $X_0=0$. The frog jumps $1$ step right with
>   probability $p$ and jumps 1 step left with probaibility $q$ at each
>   time step, independently of what happened before, until it reaches
>   either the point $a=-10$ or the point $b=+30$, which are sticky: if
>   the frog reaches one of them, it stays there forever.
>
> Let $X_n$ denote the position of the frog after n steps (for
>   $n=0,1,2,...$). $Y_n:=(\frac{q}{p})^{X_n}$.
>
> Show that $Y_n$ converges almost surely to some limiting random
>   variable $Y_{\infty}$. What are the possible values of $Y_{\infty}$?

My solution: We can first show that $X_n$ converges almost surely. It is obvious that $X_n$ will converge to 
$$X_{\infty}=\begin{cases} 30\\ -10 \end{cases}$$

I need to show $P(X_n=30)\rightarrow c_1$($c_1$ is some constant), and $P(X_n=-10)\rightarrow c_2$($c_2$ is some constant).

So let $a,b$ be the times of steps the frog jumps to right and left in the first n-th steps.

Suppose $n$ is large enough, to make $X_n=30$ we need $a-b\geqslant 30$, since $a+b=n$ so we get the inequality that $n-2b\geqslant 30$, so $b\leqslant \frac{n}{2}-15$. So
$$P(X_n=30)=\sum_{i=0}^{[\frac{n}{2}]-15}\binom{n}i p^{n-i}q^i,$$
and

$$P(X_n=-10)=\sum_{i=[\frac{n}{2}]+5}^n \binom{n}i p^{n-i}q^i.$$

*My question is: Is this method right and how to show that these two summations converge?*

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should use Kolmogorov three-series theorem.

Comment: If $p=\frac 1 2$, then $X_n$ is a martingale. If $p\ne \frac 1 2$, $Y_n$ is a martingale. Either way, use optional stopping theorem.